# I see 'a job that interests you', why not 'a job that you interest'?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

Book [Great Writing 2, Forth edition](https://eltngl.com/search/productOverview.do?N=4294918395+200&Ntk=P_EPI&Ntt=200393792918210441784750985321831204089&Ntx=mode%2Bmatchallpartial&homePage=false), page 96

> TOPIC 4: Write about ***a job that interests you***. Include the title of
> the job, the duties of the job, and why it is interesting to you.

[image]

I see ***a job that interests you***, why not ***a job that you interest***?

Comment: That is how the verb is used.

Comment: English is my foreign language, could you explain that grammar rule in easy-to-understand way?

Comment: In your version, it would mean that you are doing something to the job, but it's the other way round.

Comment: Is it the same with this reference https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that#:~:text=That%3A%20relative%20pronoun ?

Comment: It is "*That*: relative pronoun."

Comment: It should be "I **saw** a job that interests you".  It's the job that is interesting to the person, not the person who is interesting to the job.

Comment: I could refer to *a **person** that you interest* (meaning a person who thinks you are interesting). But I can't talk about *a **job** that you interest*, because (as implied above), jobs aren't capable of being interested in anything or anyone.

Comment: On this site, we don't allow images without the full text typed out. People with screen readers can't read text in images, and people searching the site for words in the image won't find this question. Please type out only the words you need to ask this question, and remove the image.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confused because 'interest' can be a noun as well as a verb. Also, we have 'interested' and 'interesting', which are adjectives. They are all used differently, of course.

For example, you could say:

- I have an **interest** in languages. (noun)
- I am **interested** in languages. (adjective)
- I find languages **interesting** (adjective).
- Languages **interest** me. (verb)

'Interest' as a verb is transitive, and the object it holds is the person that the subject is having an effect on. So, for example, "*languages interest me*" means that the speaker finds themselves interested by languages. Your example is correct. "A job that interests you" means that the job would cause you to be interested.